# Unable to find css property

Tags: php, css, html, user-interface

I have used HTML5 template to build a simple web site http://glassta.com , however from past one week i am struggling with a css issue. From attached image you can see there is a gap in right hand side and bottom. Can you please help me to identify the html element creating that gap and how to fix it. Please let me know if you require any other information. Web site url - http://glassta.com

[image: Image with issue]

Comment: From what I can tell, your carousel is initializing too early. When the page is loaded and I resize 1px the gap goes away. Please see when you INIT the carousel, if the page has completed running.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is issue with carousel. I have commented many sections from default theme page. if i allow few more contents it closes the gap without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem is when the page loads, there is a massive height that pops up. I'm guessing it's the carousel items that's stacked underneath each other. This causes the vertical scroll bar to appear. The carousel then initializes but is taking the width of the viewport that contains the scroll bar. After the INIT the scroll bar hides and you're left with the space it took up.

I haven't used that library yet so I'm not sure how you'd go about fixing the issue. Maybe place an `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for looking into it. I was able to resolve gap in right side using your method. However still there is a gap in bottom. When i inspect bottom gap it points me to html and when i placed same style="overflow: hidden;" in html it did not resolve. It would be great if you could look into below gap.

Comment: I will look in to it. Please update your questions if you can. I'm just not 100% sure if I'll be able to do it this weekend :). Will try my best.

Comment: Hi Gezzasa, I have found solution and updated this post. Thanks to you for pointing out carousal as issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing valuable clues, i looked into master slider documentation http://www.masterslider.com/doc/#quickstart and found the slider height is controlled by javascript not css.

I have modified javascript width and height to solve the problem. This javascript will in your index.php page.

slider.setup('masterslider', {
                width: 1400, // slider standard width
                height: 620, // slider standard height
                space: 1,
                layout: 'fullwidth',
                loop: true,
                preload: 0,
                instantStartLayers: true,
                autoplay: true
            });